# References for the functor of points vision of schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory

I recently discovered the idea of the functor of points. I would like to find a reference where the different visions of scheme are presented.

It seems to me that the classical texts emphasize the classical vision of locally ringed spaces. I don't know the reason for this, isn't the functorial definition supposed to make some constructions easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read *The Geometry of Schemes* by Eisenbud and Harris, whose last  chapter is about functorial viewpoint, or *Introduction to algebraic geometry and algebraic groups* by Demazure and Gabriel which is written essentially with functorial viewpoint.

The classical vision of locally ringed spaces is generally emphasized because it may seem less abstract at first sight for a beginner which knows classical varieties : indeed, schemes can be seen as "enriched varieties", which seems better suited for geometric intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at the construction of Hilbert and Quot schemes from FGA Explained by Nitin Nitsure (also available in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504590 ). It has some concrete examples such as realizing Projective spaces and  Grassmannians as objects that represents some particular kind of Quot functors.